# Using Strcat to create dynamic variable names

Tags: matlab, eval

I have a process which is repeated on a set of data stored in separate folders. Each time a certain folders data is processed I need new variable names as I need to results separate after the initial processing is finished for more processing. 
For example at the start of each new block of the repeated function I declare sets of arrays

`Set_1 = zeros(dim, number);`

```
vectors_1 = zeros(dim, number);
```

For the next set of data I need:

```
`Set_2 = .........`
```

and so on. There is going to be alot of these sets so I need a way to automate the creation of these variables, and the use the new variables names in the function whilst maintaining that they are separate once all the functions are completed.

I first tried using `strcat('Set_1',int2str(number)) = zeros(dim, number)` but this does not work, I believe because it means I would be trying to set an array as a string. I'm sure there must be a way to create one function and have the variables dynamically created but it seems to be beyond me, so it's probably quite obvious, so if anyone can tell me a way that would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd not do it like this. It's a bad habit, it's better to use a cell array or a struct to keep multiple sets. There is a small overhead (size-wise) per field, but it'll be a lot easier to maintain later on.

If you really, really want to do that use `eval` on the string you composed.

Comment: Can you please explain more on how to use a cell array or a struct data type for dynamic variable names?
I was using this to let a user set the name of a variable:

    eval([var2n '=' num2str(var2v)]);
where var2n is the string entered by the user

Comment: Use a struct with "dot-paren" notation for dynamic field names. 
`s = struct; n = 12; var2v = '123.456'; var2n = sprintf('foo_%d', n); s.(var2n) = num2str(var2v);`

Comment: Or using a cell array: `Sets=cell(nSets,1);vectors=cell(nSets,1); for k=1:nSets, Sets{k}=zeros(dim,number); vectors{k}=zeros(dim,number); end`

Comment: Thank you for your answers, one more question; Do the matrices inside a cell array all have to be the same dimensions, for example all of my matrices are different sizes: (5,107) to (70890,133). Each run through the function is a set of data from a different image and the various arrays I need each time include small and very large arrays for each I need to access each separately.

Comment: A cell array can contain whatever data you want it to contain. So different sizes matrices is no problem whatsoever.

Comment: Ok thank you, sorry to keep asking but you're proving very useful, what about matrices of the same name, can they be different sizes? i.e Set{1} = zeros(dim, 107}, Set{2} = zeros(dim, 50} etc I hoping in the for loop I can use an array of different sizes and index by k `Sets{k}=zeros(dim, sizeArray(k))`

Comment: Yeah, sure, that's what I meant to say in the first place. Like this is perfectly good: `m=cell(3,1); m{1}='foo';m{2}=speye(100);m{3}=struct('foo','bar','qsd',1);`

Answer (score 4):

The MATLAB function [genvarname](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/genvarname.html) does what you want. In your case it would look something like:

```
eval(genvarname('Set_', who)) = zeros(dim, number);
```

However, I would follow the recommendations of previous answers and use a cell or struct to store the results.

Answer (score 3):

This sort of pattern is *considered harmful* since it requires the `eval` function. See one of the following for techniques for avoiding it:

- http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/tech-notes/1100/1103.html
- http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/

If you insist on using `eval`, then use something like:

```
eval(sprintf('Set_1%d = zeros(dim, number);', number))
```